# Reshape multiple copies of a set of columns in R both Wide > Long and Long > Wide

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

I'm converting to R from STATA.
One thing I am struggling to replicate nicely is the reshape function in STATA.
In STATA roughly this can be done with:

```
reshape wide variable names, i(Unique person ID) j(ID identifying each entry per unique ID i)
```

I have a dataset containing intra-venous lines used by patients (sample now attached).The data is currently Long (1 row per) line. For each line you will see there are several columns; line-type, insertion date, removal date etc.

I'd like to understand how best to reshape layout 1 to wide and layout 2 back to long. Each patient has a unique ID. I can label each row per person with a unique ID (i.e number rows within ID_Var 1:n). Example of Wide / Long desired layouts below.

[image: Theoretical Long and Wide Dataset layout]

This feels different from examples of Reshaping I have seen on Stackoverflow (and that are described in the dplyr cheatsheet) - because normally they would be reshaping based on say the value in the line column - and you would be making a new column called peripheral and taking the value from inserted and putting it in peripheral column, and making another column called Hickman, and putting the inserted value into that column etc.
Typical DPLYR example (not the aim here)

[image: DPLYR type examples]

I'm happy for a base or dplyr (or indeed alternative) solution....
I've tried using reshape in R::base and had a look at spread in dplyr but couldn't get either to work ?because I'm trying to do it all in 1 step (which is what I would do in STATA).

For example I tried

`lines_wide <- reshape(lines,idvar=lines$Episode,timevar=lines$n,direction="wide")`

But I get:
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , idvar) : undefined columns selected

I also tried specifying specific elements to reshape using v.names:

```
lines_wide <- reshape(lines,idvar=lines$Episode,timevar=lines$n,direction="wide", v.names = list(lines$Site,lines$Line.Type,lines$Removal.Reason))
```

But I get the same error.

An example of the long dataset is here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h0lo910ix304qj3/reshape_example.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question I will also recommend to take a look at the [_how do I ask a good question_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's also generally good to demonstrate you already put some effort into it.

Comment: Apologies - I have added a link to a copy of some sample data and some examples of what I have tried using the base:reshape command.

Comment: The link to the sample dataset is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should provide at least your data... Anyways, here a `tidyverse`-solution, using `tidyr` and `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(~patient, ~line, ~inserted, ~complications,
          1,"peripheral", "01/02/17", "none",
          1,"peripheral", "04/02/17", "blocked")

# this prefix preserves the order of your variables:
names(df)[-1] <- c("[1]line", "[2]inserted", "[3]complications")

df_wide <- 
  df %>% 
  group_by(patient) %>% 
  mutate(nr = seq_len(n())) %>% # number of observations for each patient
  gather(key = key, value = value, -patient, -nr) %>% # make Long
  arrange(nr, key) %>% # sort by nr and variable name to keep you order
  unite(key, nr, key, sep = ".") %>% # paste variable number and variable name
  mutate(key = factor(key, levels = unique(key))) %>% # tells spread to preserve order
  spread(key = key, value = value) # make wide again

# remove the prefix from above
names(df_wide) <- names(df_wide) %>% 
               gsub(pattern = "\\[\\d{1}\\]", 
               replacement = "")

df_wide

  patient   `1.line` `1.inserted` `1.complications`   `2.line` `2.inserted` `2.complications`
*   <dbl>      <chr>        <chr>             <chr>      <chr>        <chr>             <chr>
1       1 peripheral     01/02/17              none peripheral     04/02/17           blocked
```

And the other way round:

```
df_long <- 
  df_wide %>%
  gather(key = key, value = value, -patient) %>% 
  separate(key, into = c("nr", "key")) %>% 
  spread(key = key, value = value) %>% 
  select(patient, line, inserted, complications)

df_long

  patient       line inserted complications
*   <dbl>      <chr>    <chr>         <chr>
1       1 peripheral 01/02/17          none
2       1 peripheral 04/02/17       blocked
```

Comment: Edit: Placed `arrange` before `unite`, just to allow proper order if 10 or more lines per Patient occur. Also added the example to transform back to initial data frame.